# When we set "selectable: true" in scheduler option, scheduler get focus it jumps

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

We are using Kendo UI v2016.3.1118. When we set  "selectable: true" in scheduler option in that case, scheduler get focus and it jumps. We tried by removing  "selectable: true" and added  "selectable: false" so in that case is it working fine but i didn't get the selected event, which is require. This behaviour is for chrome as well as IE 11

The solution we got from kendo team was not working in IE it is only working in chrome. Open following link in IE it will show what issue we are facing.
https://dojo.telerik.com/ULOhelAw
https://dojo.telerik.com/ULOhelAw/19
Let me any better solution that will work in IE as well as in chrome.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the code in `kendo.ui.Scheduler.fn._mouseDownSelection`? If I remove the whole block, it seems to behave okay. What are you missing if you remove this block?

Comment: Use this link in IE https://dojo.telerik.com/ULOhelAw/25. 
1)Make sure that scroll bar of window is in middle of the page. 
2) When scheduler is half focus, click on scheduler cell. 
3) When you click on scheduler it get jump up and scheduler get focus. 
I need to fix that jumping issue when scheduler is half open/ middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old topic, but if someone is looking for answer I can share my work around. The problem I faced was that when none of events where selected and i tried to open context menu scheduler scrolled to the top, so what I did I marked event as selected on hover. That fixed an issue:

```
$("#scheduler").on("mouseenter", ".k-event", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);
    var uid = target.data("uid");
    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
        $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").select(null);
        $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").select([uid]);
        //alert("mouserenter, uid: " + uid);
    }
});
```